# Why does this records repeating in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

When I execute query:

```
SELECT
  follow.fgid,
  up.upblog,
  up.dataid,
  `data`.`name`,
  `data`.image,
  up.upid,
  up.datecreated
FROM follow
  INNER JOIN up
    ON follow.fgid = up.dataid
  INNER JOIN `data`
    ON `data`.dataid = follow.fgid
WHERE follow.frid = '$_SESSION[userid]'
     OR up.dataid = '$_SESSION[userid]'
```

I got next output:

```
fgid  upblog    dataid  name       upid  datecreated

6     postno1   6       himanshu     1     2014=05-29
4     postno5   4       chin         1     2014=05-29
2     postno6   2       hit          1     2014=05-29
1     postno7   1       meet         1     2014=05-29
1     postno7   1       meet         1     2014=05-29
1     postno7   1       meet         1     2014=05-29
1     postno7   1       meet         1     2014=05-29
1     postno7   1       meet         1     2014=05-29
1     postno7   1       meet         1     2014=05-29
4     postno8   4       chin         1     2014=05-29
```

Why does this records repeating in MySQL?

Comment: use GROUP BY in QUERY like GROUP BY fgid

Comment: Plase show us the tabledescription. looks like there is en error in you join. Must it be `INNER JOIN `data` ON `data`.dataid = up.dataid
`

Comment: its one-to-many relation and joining will return multiple rows unless u filter out using `group by`

Comment: What is the input data that generates this issue?

Comment: Your select has 7 columns but you are showing us the data for only 6 columns. "data.image" column is missing from output posted by you. Please correct it so that we can analyze.

Comment: Also, As @AbhikChakraborty commented there are chances you are in one-to-many relationship and it seems that your "data" table is culprit in this case. you can use 'group by' to filter.

Comment: Or use DISTINCT, which would work in other flavours of SQL as well.

Comment: @SankalpBhatt image column show only image file name and it's not a question bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to obtain only distinct values from your query, you need to replace `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT` 
The matter because they repeat, depends on data in your tables and `join` and `where` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You join the tables by dataid (which you call fgid in the follows table). I suppose this is the primary key of the data table. But it is not unique in the tables follow and up. So, say you have three entries for dataid 1 in follow and two in up than you get six in total (three times two).

Use the following commands to see the records in the tables:

```
SELECT * from follow where fgid = 1;
```

and

```
SELECT * from up where dataid = 1;
```

This gives you the information why you see duplicate records in your results. Then think about what you *want* to see. Maybe just show an additional field in your results, so your records are no longer duplicates? Or do you want to see all combinations, but each just once? Then use DISTINCT. Or do you want to see the maximum date and minimum upblog etc. in your results? Then group by dataid and aggregate all other columns according to your wishes.